# How do I use react-query to synchronously join data from different react-query hooks together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I have three different data types: `Books`, `Authors`, and `Publishers`. I use react-query to fetch a list of each type, i.e. `useBooks(bookIds)`, `useAuthors(authorIds)`, `usePublishers(publisherIds)` and this works great when I try to use them independently of each other.

However, a book has a list of `authorIds` and `publisherIds` and I want to join the `Publishers` and `Authors` objects to the `Books`. I can't figure out the right way to do this using react-query. Ideally I'd like to be able to call all three hooks, wait for their response, and then return it as one big hook. However, I cannot wrap my head around to do this.

One implementation I tried was to make each hook that joins data to `Book` dependent on the results of a previous hook. This works okay; however the big problem with this is that the joins are done asynchronously from one another; the data the component consumes cannot expect a `Book` to have a `Author` or `Publisher` once the data is returned. Here's an example:

```
const usePopulatedBooks = (bookIds) => {
    const booksQuery = useBooks(bookIds);

    const {data: books} = booksQuery;

    const authorIds = [];
    const publisherIds = [];

    if (books) {
        books.forEach(book => {
            authorIds.push(book.authorId);
            authorIds.push(book.publisherIds);
        })
    }

    // Who knows when this finishes?
    const {data: authors} = useAuthors(authorIds);

    // Who knows when this finishes?
    const {data: publishers} = usePublishers(publisherIds);

    // Adds "author" and "publisher" field (if the authors/publishers array exist) to "book"
    const joinedBooks = joinData(books, authors, publishers);

    return {...booksQuery, data: joinedBooks};
}
```

Is there some way I can write the above logic in a way such that nothing returns until all data has been joined? In my head the way I'd do this is call all three hooks in a query function of another react-query hooks, but hooks rules don't let me do this.

Comment: Do you have control of the back-end/API? If so, this type of thing would be so much more easily solved by just having an endpoint that provides that data already joined. Doing this from the front-end is painful without GraphQL.

Answer (score 10):

Without knowing how your `useBooks`, `useAuthors`, and `usePublishers` hooks work internally, I can't answer precisely, but I'd approach the problem by writing a function that does all your API calls, then wrap that single function with `useQuery`. You don't want to conditionally call different hooks as that violates one of the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html): "Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions."

Something like this:

```js
async function getBookDetails() {
    const books = await getAllBooks();
    const authorIds = books.map(x => x.authorId);
    const authors = await getAuthorsForIds(authorIds);
    const publisherIds = books.map(x => x.publisherId);
    const publishers = await getPublishersForIds(publisherIds);
    return { books, authors, publishers };
}
```

Then you can wrap it in a useQuery like this:

```js
const result = useQuery("book-details", getBookDetails);
```

This assumes that if there are no results for any of the queries, you get an empty array `[]`, not null or undefined.

If you're not familiar with `Array.map`, you can read up on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).